Is it safe to run the AC for a extended time, when the condenser breaker is off?
In spring, we have very mild weather. Would it be safe to turn off the condenser breaker, and let the AC run, to just roll around the air in the house?

Does the AC not have a fan only setting?

As noted in several answers, you can do this from your thermostat without turning the breaker off but also note: A lot of new thermostats in the $40+ range (you don't have to spend $200) will have functions to run only the fan on programmed cycles like 15 minutes on 15 minutes off, etc.     You can leave the breakers on.  If the temp rises the full A/C will come on as needed.  If it drops, the fan will cycle, rather than running 100% of the time.

As noted by @jay613 there's a common feature on newer thermostats to run the HVAC blower periodically to mix up the air for filtration and even out the temperature. For the thermostats I've had the fan settings include 'auto' (run with heating or cooling), 'on' (just on all the time, and 'circulate' (run for 20 minutes per hour). If your thermostat doesn't have a circulate feature then perhaps get a new thermostat that does, or run the fan continuously during mild parts of the year. If there is no fan control on the thermostat then it is likely very old and in need of replacement regardless.

Upgrade your thermostat.  Most thermostats have a "Fan Only" switch to do exactly what you want, however, thermostats are sold in many grades of product "good/better/best" and the "Fan Only" switch is deleted on the cheaper grades.
A normal A/C enabled thermostat has 4 wires:

R = red = 24V supply (from furnace)
W = white = Call for Heat (to furnace)
G = green = Call for Blower (to furnace/air handler)
Y = yellow = Call for A/C (to A/C compressor)

The thermostat shunts (shorts) R to W when heat is needed.   Most furnaces know when to run the blower (when the burner is hot enough so it doesn't blast cold air around) and the thermostat doesn't need to tell it to do that.
When A/C is needed, it shunts R to G to get the furnace to run its blower for the air handling, and also, R to Y to get the A/C compressor to run.
The "Fan Only" switch simply manually shunts R to G.  That's it.
Now if your thermostat cable only has 3 wires, it's possible someone set it up to share G and Y from the thermostat to the furnace. Pull a 6-wire or better thermostat cable. (spare room for a "C" wire for smart 'stats).

Perhaps a needless nit pick but not all furnaces will run the fan all it's own, requiring the thermostat to run the fan.  Many thermostats will accommodate this with an internal jumper or switch, or with programmable thermostats a setting in some menu.  I agree on a call to upgrade the thermostat, and to run a new cable with a common wire if possible.

@MacGuffin ok edited.

In most cases it will be OK if the air handler and compressor/condenser have separate breakers. Usually, it's better to just turn the thermostat setting to "fan only" and that will allow the fan to run without the condenser ever turning on.

It depends on design. Traditionally, an air conditioner made use of a furnace air handler to distribute air. Basically the air handler is a big box that has:

A blower fan to circulate hot or cold or ambient temperature air
A burner (gas or oil) or heating element (a.k.a., giant toaster - electric resistance heat)
An evaporator coil to (essentially) use the air conditioner to cool the inside air
A control board
An air filter

and sometimes additional components such as a humidifier or electronic air filter.
With this setup, the blower can be run by itself. Typically the thermostat will have a main fan setting of "On", "Off" or "Auto". "Auto" means run the blower only when the heat or air conditioning is running. "On" means run the blower all the time. If you set the fan to "On" and set the desired temperature far above (air conditioning) or below (heating) the ambient temperature then you have the fan running all the time without running the rest of the system.
If you have a built-in control system (instead of a separate thermostat) on a mini-split system then it may or may not have a "fan only" setting, and then a way to do this will depend on the specific design. Simply turning off the breaker for part of the system may work just fine, but may either not work as desired or possibly even lead to damage. Unknown without more details.

You are speaking of just running the fan in the air handler and that is ok.
There should be a setting on the thermostat such as "FAN ON" that will make the fan run.  Set the temperature to a setting high enough that the AC will not come on.
The fan will run and circulate the air, but the condenser will not run. No need to turn off a breaker.  But be aware the fan will run constantly until you switch it to "OFF"  or "AUTO"

If the temprature is set correctly on the thermostat, can I leave it at AUTO, that says at least 5 minutes each hour?

@Nate Yes, you can leave it at AUTO but if your in a hot, humid climate, the condenser  could run a lot more than 5 minutes an hour.

An ordinary thermostat will not run the air conditioning (or heat) 'x minutes an hour' - it will run as much as needed. However, I have seen some reports of fancier thermostats designed to specifically run a certain minimum duty cycle. That can make sense in certain situations - e.g., not very hot but very high humidity.
